# How to add each value of one column beneath its corresponding row of another column without mixing up the order in R

Tags: r, merge

I couln't find a solution / an answer to this question, hence ask you guys :-)

I have the following merging challenge as represented in the example below: How to add each value (each arbitrary, no sorting possible) of one column beneath its corresponding row of another column without mixing up the order in R? I cannot sort the columns, the values are arbitrary. This is just an example to make the system clear.

Dataframe before:

```
         column1                column2
valueColumn1row1       valueColumn2row1
valueColumn1row2       valueColumn2row2
               .                      .
               .                      .
               .                      .
```

Dataframe after:

```
          finalcolumn            
     valueColumn1row1
     valueColumn2row1       
     valueColumn1row2
     valueColumn2row2 
               .                      
               .                      
               .
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `matrix[matrix]` subsetting:

```
# create example data
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = letters[1:6],
    col2 = letters[21:26],
    stringsAsFactors = F
)

# convert data to a matrix
dfm <- as.matrix(df)

# create a subsetting-matrix of the elements that you want, in the order that you want
j <- ncol(dfm)
sub <- matrix(c(rep(1:nrow(df), each=j), rep(1:j, nrow(df))), ncol=2)

# create the desired column
dfm[sub]
```

Example data

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    a    u
2    b    v
3    c    w
4    d    x
5    e    y
6    f    z
```

Result

```
> data.frame(dfm[sub])
   dfm.sub.
1         a
2         u
3         b
4         v
5         c
6         w
7         d
8         x
9         e
10        y
11        f
12        z
```

Comment: I am sorry for my question not being clear (and just tried to specify it), I cannot sort the columns, all values are arbitrary chosen.